# How to protect Web API from CSRF attack if it called from cross domain client?

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, csrf, csrf-protection

I have a Web API and that is called by cross domain client application developed in angular. How I can protect my Web API from CSRF attack.

I am using Token based authentication

I went through following article by Mike Wasson
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks

But in the above case also client and web api is running in same domain,
if it in different domain how we can pass AntiForgeryToken?

Answer (score 0):

What about creating an endpoint which you can query when your application starts to get the tokens? Then send them along with every future request from the angular app.

```
public class AntiForgeryController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        string cookieToken;
        string formToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);

        return Ok(new {cookieToken, formToken});
    }
}
```

Comment: Attacker also will get to know about this call, then he can simply call and pass this value along with request right?

Comment: Sure, that is possible. You will have to make this endpoint require some type of authentication.